# Send $http.get twice

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, angular-http, angularjs-factory

**Edit 1: Guys, I notice that I call $http.get('/posts') (for some special purpose) in my authentication factory. Sorry for the stupid question. I will delete it when the bounty is end.**

I have the following code to load a page `https://localhost:3000/#/home`, which get all the posts from the database and display them.

The problem is that, I realise the log `router.get /posts` is print twice, whereas `here` and `there` are only alerted once.

Does anyone know if it means that `$http.get` is undertaken twice? If so, where is the problem?

```
app.config(... ...) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('global', {
            templateUrl: '/htmls/global.html',
            controller: 'GlobalCtrl'
        })
        .state('global.home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: '/htmls/home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl',
            resolve: {
                postPromise: ['posts', function (posts) {
                    return posts.getAll();
                }]
            }
        });
}]);

app.factory('posts', ['$http', 'auth', function ($http, auth) {
    var o = { posts: [] };

    o.getAll = function () {
        alert("before");
        return $http.get('/posts').then(function (res) {
            alert("after");
            angular.copy(res.data, o.posts);
        })
    }
    ... ...
}]);

app.controller('GlobalCtrl', [function () { }]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'posts', 'auth', 'postPromise', function ($scope, posts, auth, postPromise) {
    ... ...
```

In the backend:

```
router.get('/posts', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("router.get /posts");
    Post.find(function (err, posts) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(posts);
    });
});
```

**PS:** I just realised one thing: I had set a login and logout on the website. When I am NOT logged in, `https://localhost:3000/#/home` only shows once `router.get /posts`; the problem raises when I am logged in.

Comment: Is the angular app and the API on a different domain?

Comment: what API do you refer to? I think the angular app is in `https://localhost:3000`, right?

Comment: The API to get the posts. Trying to work out if it is a CORS issue. When looking at network traffic in Chrome, is there an OPTIONS and GET request?

Comment: It is a mean-stack application. I host everything in `localhost:3000`, I don't think it is CORS...

Comment: By searching `localhost` in the whole project, and I have found `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/news');`, I tried to change to `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:3000/news');`, but it raised an error.

Comment: Can you mention how the route is activated. i,e href or ui-sref?

Comment: You can look at `console.trace()` to find who called it second time. Put it in `o.getAll` method

Comment: Could you also post your code that handles logging in? And in which state you are when you try to log in?

Comment: @MattTester I think you are onto something, it's most likely preflight call that's not handled properly before getting to router

Comment: It may be possible that controller is called twice, one by route & other by template i.e ng-controller ="". Please check that if that is the cause

Comment: @MattTester there is no OPTIONS request.

Comment: @KannanJ It is always by `$stateProvider.state(...`, I didn't use `href` or`ui-sref`.

Comment: @Leguest I tried to put `console.trace()` before `return $http.get('/posts').then(function (res) {` or after. It only displays once, and there is no difference between logged-in mode and logged-out mode.

Comment: Guys, I notice that I call `$http.get('/posts')` (for some special purpose) in my authentication factory. Sorry for the stupid question. I will delete it soon... Thank you...

Comment: @SoftTimur sooner than later please .... or at least make a note in the original post so others do not waste time thinking about this.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are saying that when you are logged the problem occurs...this is because of the fact that since you are using angular-ui-router the two events are very important.

```
$stataChangeStart(...) , and $stateChangeSuccesss(...)
```

Please be informed that the resolve which you are using

```
.state('global.home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: '/htmls/home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl',
            resolve: {
                postPromise: ['posts', function (posts) {
                    return posts.getAll();
                }]
            }
        })
```

is first resolved before the jump happens to the target url and then the view gets changed/updated.

One solutions is:

Please make sure that you have '&&' condition to be checked here as you are trying to login first and then get the data.

If you are using the angular ui router version 0.12 , please upgrade the version so that the issue resolves.
Thanks.